# Magento Cron Error

Tags: magento-1.7, error, cron, schedule

I am working on a custom Magento module and set up two Cron job for it. Every thing is working fine. I want to execute one process every hour for this i have used `<cron_expr>0 * * * *</cron_expr>` and another process will execute on daily at midnight for this i have used    `<cron_expr>0 0 * * *</cron_expr>`. working fine. I have used custom code to `reindex` magento data after completing every process. But sometimes I got below error message when two process is working together. Please help me.

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Catalog URL Rewrites Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.'

exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Product Prices Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error pretty much for the exact reason it gives you. It is not possible to have two independent indexing jobs running side by side without running into major database issues and data loss.

I will be entirely honest and state that I would question any hourly cron task which rebuilds a full index on each run.

The only real fix per-se here is to either not build the indexes every hour and rethink what you are trying to accomplish. I.e. There is no way to simply get around that error.

Comment: Thanks for response and i m sorry for late reply. Actually i am adding products from web services and web services update their services (price and quantity) every 15 minutes.